# Where should put debian package of ceph for pi

Tags: raspbian, debian, packages

so where should I put upload the .deb file when done. Their dot lib for the doc's if anyknows of a package for this please give me a heads up about it.

Comment: Could you try and explain the question a bit more? Currently it appears to be quite confusing as to what you need an answer for. (Thanks and welcome to Pi Stackexchange!)

Comment: where good share my .deb file that i have made

Comment: lenik: saras has a new package, not available from ceph.com

Answer (score 1):

you should not download .deb package, but read [Getting Started](http://ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-start/) first, it clearly recommends to do the following to enable automatic install (and updates!):

```
wget -q -O- 'https://ceph.com/git/?p=ceph.git;a=blob_plain;f=keys/release.asc' | sudo apt-key add -
echo deb http://ceph.com/debian/ $(lsb_release -sc) main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ceph.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ceph
```

Comment: i need to upload the package i build form source as all can upload to github my deb